# How can i find file sizes with powershell

Tags: powershell

We're migrating servers and sometimes the copy of various files doesn't happen successfully and, for example, we end up with PDF files that are 1kb rather than their actual size.

I wrote a simple powershell script to find these files, but it also listed the empty subfolders at the end of the search results.  So i'd see something like this in my output text file -
C:\path\filename1.pdf
c:\path\filename2.pdf
c:\path\subfolder\

What' i'm trying to do is eliminate the empty folders in the results.  I've modified the original script -

```
Clear
$username = $env:username
Get-ChildItem -path "C:\users\blah\blah\blah\" -recurse | Where 
{$_.Length -lt 1025 } | Sort-Object length | ft fullname, length -AutoSize 
|Out-File "C:\Users\$username\Desktop\1kb_Files.txt"
```

In the modified script i've created a read-host to grab the file size to search, but then when i add that variable into the script i get an error.  Here's hte modified script -

```
$Size = Read-Host "Enter search size"
$folder = Read-Host "Enter full search path"
Get-ChildItem -path $folder -recurse |Where {($_.Length -lt '$size') -and ($_.Length -gt '0')}
```

But now i get this error - 
Cannot convert value "$size" to type "System.Int64". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."

I'm guessing i need to define the size for $size?

Comment: I would investigate the root cause of "copy of various files doesn't happen successfully" - that sounds not so good. `robocopy` can be pretty helpful for replicating files.

Comment: agreed.  different group is looking into root cause,  i'm the "fix the dang files!" guy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add the switch "-File" to the get-childitem command, remove the single quotes enclosing $Size in the where command as they prevent PowerShell from substituting the value of the Size variable for the string '$Size'. You can then remove the second clause of the where statement to finish like so:

```
$Size = Read-Host "Enter search size"
$folder = Read-Host "Enter full search path"
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse -Path $folder | Where $_.Length -lt $Size
```

Comment: Edit - carbon error there.  This does work.  Thanks FloydVincent!  it's what i needed.